# Wordpress hook called before file iterator loaded all files

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I am detecting and loading all my custom Gutenberg blocks through the following function in my theme's `functions.php`:

```php
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/blocks/*/**.php') as $file) {
    include_once($file);
}
```

In each folder `./blocks/FOLDER` there is an `gutenberg-init.php` and a `render.php`.

```
wp-content/themes/my-theme
|-- ...
|-- blocks
|   |-- block
|       |-- gutenberg-init.php
|       |-- render.php
|   |-- block
|       |-- gutenberg-init.php
|       |-- render.php
|   |-- ...
|-- ...
```

The `gutenberg-init.php` calls:

```php
add_action('acf/init', fn() => 
    acf_register_block_type([
        // ... block configuration
    ]);
);
```

In the Gutenberg editor I find 5/12 blocks that I have registered. If I do

`add_action('acf/init',  fn() => var_dump("ACF initialized"))`

right before the directory loop, as well as a `var_dump( $file )` in the file iterator, I see that the 5 files are printed and therefore loaded first, then `ACF initialized` is printed, then the remaining files are printed, meaning the hook fires before my loop has finished running.

I am aware of the difference of `foreach` and `for` loops in javascript as the `foreach` puts a callback onto the callstack for each element instead of executing the loop-code before proceeding. I never ran into similar issues using PHP and I am a bit confused on how to fix the problem. Any suggestions on how to get the file loop to finish before the remaining wordpress boot-logic proceeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple possibilities:

1. [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-init/#:%7E:text=if%20a%20field%20value%20is%20loaded%20during%20the%20functions.php%20file) state that acf/init can be "triggered early if a field value is loaded during the functions.php file".  If one of those includes is getting a field value immediately, that could be causing the behavior you're seeing.
2. Seems much less likely, but similarly, one of those files could be doing a direct call to `do_action('acf/init')`